# what does 'do correspondence with' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I receive an email from a person I know and I am reporting back some important ideas, it says 'keep doing correspondence with me,' what does that phrase mean? Does it just mean keep emailing him or I should speak to him directly?

Comment: Looking up 'correspondence' in a reputable dictionary, does one find that there is a requirement that it be face-to-face?

Comment: I should've, 'communication by letters or e-mail' from Merriam Webster dict,  Google's definition mislead me... I don't think so. Thanks.

Comment: It means that the person is not an English native speaker or is not very literate. He means "corresponding" but would have done better to write "keep in touch" or "stay in contact".

Comment: @David by 'native', are you referring to any country-specific usage like British or American? Or just English language in general?

Comment: Actually "native English speaker" is more usual, but its meaning is someone whose "mother tongue" or first language is English. The problem is the use of "do". This is because some other languages tend to have a single verb (faire in French) for the English "do" and "make", or if they have analagous words (tun and machen in German) do not use them in the same way. However, in recent times expression like "do lunch" have entered the vernacular, but "do correspondence" is just horrible — sounds like someone who only knows one verb and uses it with any noun. Don't do it ;-)

Comment: @David Thanks for your perspective. What's a better way instead of 'do'?

Comment: Better than using (do + noun) is to use the verb related to the noun if it exists and fits. Here "corresponding" is the verb form that could replace "do correspondence". However I think this sounds unnaturally formal for email, and would in any case prefer a simpler expression. It depends on the context. "Keep in touch" might do for general contact. However if you are sending this person ideas frequently I would perhaps have written something like "keep the ideas coming".

Answer (score 2):

"keep doing correspondence with me" is not idiomatic BrE. The following all are:

- "keep corresponding with me"
- "keep on corresponding with me"
- "keep up  the correspondence with me"

Comment: what does BrE mean?

Comment: British English. Commonly used abbreviation on this site, but I am sorry if its meaning was not clear to you.